# How to send push notification when the car comes to a specific radius

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-process

I want to send a push notification to the user when the van comes within a 1km radius.

I already have the user location and the changing vehicle location. That means I already have the distance between the user and the van.

What I want is to send a push notification when that distance is equal to 1km. Push notification should be sent in all the instances. (when the app is open, in the background or killed). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GeoFencing api by google, it will create radius area and you will get notified when user enter or leave to that radius,
And it will work in background as well.

for more info read official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing).
you can find proper example on provided link.